# When I use Spring Boot to start a remote service interface I get a "missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean" exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Following is my entire stacktrace in intellijIDEA:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin\java" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:57558,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\clearity\.IntelliJIdea13\system\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;D:\Work_space\External Card Related\project_related\icpay_v3_merchant\out\production\icpay_v3_merchant;C:\Users\clearity\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\2.1.6\165b8246372a829c1915611646f6d964010656cf\groovy-all-2.1.6.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\annotations-api.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\catalina.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\commons-codec-1.6.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\ecj-4.3.1.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\el-api.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\fluent-hc-4.3.4.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\httpclient-4.3.4.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\httpclient-cache-4.3.4.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\httpmime-4.3.4.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\jasper-el.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\jasper.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\jsp-api.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\juli-6.0.41.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\servletapi-3.0.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-boot-1.1.1.RELEASE-tests.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-boot-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-boot-actuator-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-context-support-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-expression-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\tomcat-coyote.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\tomcat-dbcp.jar;D:\Work_space\Spring-boot\tomcat-util-7.0.16.jar;D:\Docs\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4-bin\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4\lib\commons-codec-1.6.jar;D:\Docs\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4-bin\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;D:\Docs\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4-bin\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4\lib\fluent-hc-4.3.4.jar;D:\Docs\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4-bin\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4\lib\httpclient-4.3.4.jar;D:\Docs\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4-bin\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4\lib\httpclient-cache-4.3.4.jar;D:\Docs\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4-bin\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4\lib\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;D:\Docs\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4-bin\httpcomponents-client-4.3.4\lib\httpmime-4.3.4.jar;C:\Download\UsefulJars\fastjson-1.1.39.jar;C:\Download\jpos-1.9.0.jar;D:\Docs\slf4j-1.7.7\slf4j-1.7.7\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar;D:\Docs\slf4j-1.7.7\slf4j-1.7.7\slf4j-nop-1.7.7.jar;D:\Docs\slf4j-1.7.7\slf4j-1.7.7\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:\Download\UsefulJars\druid-1.0.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" MerchantApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57558', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.1.RELEASE)

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:683)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:944)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:933)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at MerchantApplication.main(MerchantApplication.groovy:17)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:185)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
    ... 11 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57558', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

help me

Comment: Pelase add additional configuration, main class etc. Currently there is too little information.

Comment: Configuration
EnableAutoConfiguration
this is the annotations i use on the main class

Comment: add i also add the dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: thanks ,i already resolve this  problem,due to my addtional config values in properties

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```